# Iterate through an array with nonconsecutive integers

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that will call a function repeatedly for each value in the Fibonacci sequence. For instance, let's say I want to print the sequence number each iteration, but I also want to print it in iteration-number times in that particular iteration. I'll want my output to be

`1 1 22 333 55555 88888888 ...` and so on.

Currently, I have a for-loop set up that creates an array with the Fibonacci sequence:

```
for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
{
      fibonacci[index] = fibonacci[index] + fibonacci[index-1]+fibonacci[index-2];
}
```

I'm not sure where to proceed from here. I've experimented with adding additional for-loops both inside and outside this one, but I'm coming up short. Primarily the problem lies within the fact that the loop can't take on the sequene's nonconsecutive values.

Comment: The loop you've shown is probably wrong... be careful you don't access outside the array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a nested for loop, this means a for loop within your for loop for the repetitive display of characters.

```
            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                c = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = c;
                for(int x = 0; x < c; x++) {
                    System.out.print(c);
                }

                System.out.print(" ");
            }
```

Comment: Will do now, thought we were supposed to teach people how to fish

Comment: This is what I was trying to accomplish when I first started analyzing this problem, but I couldn't quantify my ideas in the code. Thanks for guiding me to the solution.

Comment: No problem, I am glad that I could help!